# xcode and new ios6 installation?

Tags: xcode

I am trying to install `ios6` on my `xcode 4.4.1` version 
I coudnt find how to do that .(update the xcode ?)
The last version of `iOS` i can choose for my projects is `5.1` .

How can i install it ? i must do that in order to support the `ios6` ?

```
to meet "quality standards, i must add a code here.. //code 
[self myClass] // i cant publish without this,its annoying!
if(a==5)
  a=40;
else
  a=70;
```

Thnnks

Answer (score 1):

Update your xcode to version 4.5
Once updating is complete, in **scheme** choose **More Simulators** -> Choose and install all the simulators you need.
You will be able to use iOS6.